# SoundCloud tracks take too much time play in iPhone

Tags: ios, streaming, avaudioplayer, soundcloud

I have integrated soundCloud api in my application.I am playing soundCloud songs using following code as mentioned on there api documentation.

```
      NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?client_id=%@",actiVityObj.songUrl, @"e0b860d9584b7194183a9e797dc0fc16"];


      [SCRequest performMethod:SCRequestMethodGET
                  onResource:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
             usingParameters:nil
                 withAccount:nil
      sendingProgressHandler:nil
             responseHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                 NSError *playerError;
                 audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:&playerError];
                 audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
                 audioPlayer.volume = 1.0f;
                 audioPlayer.delegate = self;

                 [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
                 if (audioPlayer == nil)
                 {
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     [audioPlayer play];
                 }
             }];
```

But problem is that it takes too much time to play song and it just ridiculous. After searching I found it first download the track and then it played. Is there any way to stream it step by step. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) if you want to stream audio.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [player preparetoPlay] before some time of play.